# Can you set a Route53 Resource Record as the IP of an EC2 instance in the same cloudformation script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I have a cloudformation script that makes an EC2 instance and sets up some alarms. I would like to add a Route53 record for this instance in the same cloudformation, but I am having trouble figuring out what to put for the Resource Record field. **Is there a way to reference the newly created EC2 instance's IP address for the ResourceRecord field of the AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup?**

I have already tried to use `"ResourceRecords":"EC2Instance"` but that got me "Encountered unsupported property Type." I don't know how else to accomplish this outside of manually setting the DNS entry after creation, but I would like to do it in one step so it is done automatically.

Here is what I have:

```
"Resources": {
    "EC2Instance": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {"ImageId": {
          "Ref": "AMI"
        },
        "IamInstanceProfile": {
          "Ref": "InstanceProfile"
        },
        "InstanceType": {
          "Ref": "InstanceSize"
        },
        "BlockDeviceMappings": [{
            "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
            "Ebs": {
              "Encrypted": true,
              "VolumeSize": 100,
              "DeleteOnTermination": false
            }
          }]
      }
    },
    "DNS": {
      "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "HostedZoneName": {"Ref": "HostedZoneName"},
        "Comment": "Alias Record",
        "ResourceRecords":"EC2Instance",
        "Type": "A",
        "Name": {"Fn::Join" : ["",[{"Ref": "ComponentDNSName"},{"Ref": "HostedZoneName"}]]}
      }
    }
  },
```

I would expect there would be someway to find the newly created IP for the EC2 instance, but I am not sure how. I am thinking I have to use an elastic IP, but I still do not know how to reference that. Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: I don't think that is supported; you would have to manually add an A record in your Route 53 hosted zone that resolves to the public IP address of your EC2 instance.   However....note that when your instance is stopped/terminated it will get a NEW public IP address, breaking your Route 53 entry.

A better approach is to put your EC2 instance(s) behind an AWS load balancer.  You can then create a Route 53 alias record to the load balancer via CloudFormation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [AWS::EC2::Instance - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html):

> `Fn::GetAtt`
>
> The `Fn::GetAtt` intrinsic function returns a value for a specified attribute of this type. The following are the available attributes and sample return values.
>
> `PrivateIp`
>
> The private IP address of the specified instance. For example: 10.24.34.0.

So, it would be something like:

```
{ "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "EC2Instance", "PrivateIp" ] }
```

Comment: By the way, you should try the YAML versions of CloudFormation templates. They are so much easier to view/edit!